# Cómo manejar error en Java

Tags: java

Estoy intentado leer un fichero de texto en Java para formar a partir de su líneas un array de enteros.
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 package Prac2;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

 public class Practica {


 public static int [] leefichero(String nombrefichero) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(new File(nombrefichero));

    int lon = entrada.nextInt();
    int [] vector = new int[lon];
    for (int i=0; i<lon; i++){
        vector[i] = entrada.nextInt();
    }
    entrada.close();
    return vector;

 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
    int result [] = leefichero("Fichero.txt");
 }

}
```

El código es sencillo, cada línea del fichero es un entero, leo la primero y defino la longitud del array y a partir de la segunda línea, cada una de ellas es un entero que introduzco en el array.

La intención es poder controlar y "lanzar" el posible error de lectura del fichero de ahí a que declare `thows FileNotFoundException` pero me produce el siguiente error:

> Error:(67, 35) java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Entiendo que lo que ocurre es que en ningún momento controlo el posible error y por lo tanto falla.

Así que la pregunta es: ¿cómo y dónde debo controlar el error de lectura del fichero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es un bloque try catch cuando llamas a la función

```
try
{
    int result [] = leefichero("Fichero.txt");
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
//maneja aquí el error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cada vez que invocas un método que pueda arrojar una *[checked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)* (cualquier excepción que no extienda de `RuntimeException` o `Error`) el compilador te obliga a hacer una de las siguientes opciones:

- Atrapar la excepción con un bloque `try {...} catch (...){...}` manejandola.
- Declarar que el método que invoca también arroja la excepción `throws ...` delegando la responsabilidad al invocador.

Es responsabilidad del programador si quiere delegar el trabajo de manejar la excepción al invocador o manejarla el mismo.